# Which is located in the Python library function "open" and how to find them?

Tags: python, file, function

Python has the "open" function that is used to read and write files. However, I would like to know in which file of Python library this function is? And how to start tracking functions and classes to find your files? 
Tried but not succeeded

Comment: its a `built-in` function !

Comment: @Kasra: built-in functions are implemented in the C source code. Perhaps that's what OP is after

Comment: @inspectorG4dget yes of course !